# Orientdb. Setting up a sharded orientdb

Tags: orientdb

orientdb version 2.1.11

I'm trying to setup on 3 nodes, I want to shard the data like the description of default-distribute-config.json.

write node1 -> node1, node2

write node2 -> node2, node3

write node3 -> node3, node1

```
{
      "autoDeploy": true,
      "hotAlignment": false,
      "executionMode": "undefined",
      "readQuorum": 1,
      "writeQuorum": 2,
      "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
      "readYourWrites": true,
      "servers": {
        "*": "master"
      },
      "clusters": {
        "internal": {
        },
        "index": {
        },
        "person_node1": {
          "servers": ["node1","node2"]
        },
        "person_node2": {
          "servers": ["node2","node3"]
        },
        "person_node3": {
          "servers": ["node3","node1"]
        },
        "*": {
          "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
        }
      }
    }
```

but when I started nodes, they didn't wok like this. Sometime they work like this (copy from log file):

```
"person_node1": {
  "servers": ["node1"]
},
"person_node2": {
  "servers": ["node2"]
},
"person_node3": {
  "servers": ["node3"]
},
"*": {
  "servers": ["node2","node1","node3","<NEW_NODE>"]
},
```

Is there any detail document describing the configuration?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is always updated by removing the absent nodes. If you want a more sticky configuration, set `"hotAlignment": true`, after 2.1.10 is safe to set it to true.

We're working on it by providing a more flexible behaviour.

Comment: thanks Lvca. But I found the document  http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Architecture.html say: hotAlignment:true could bring the database status as inconsistent. Please set it always to 'false', the default. I remember when I set to true, happened between two node cluser sync problem. No matter waht, I'm to try set true again.

Comment: I had try, it's ok. 

If I add a node, how can this new node synchronize the other node's data. Do I modify the default-distribute-config.json?

Comment: If you have the tag <NEW_NODE>, then any new joining node name takes the place of the tag, so it's automatic by default.